# multiple recipients email list for AWS SES python sdk

Tags: python, amazon-ses

How can I put multiple email recipient addresses in my ses instead of

```
RECIPIENT = "recipient@example.com"
```

or how to make it read an email list txt file line by line using this:

```
mylist = open(list.txt,r)
read_me = mylist.readlines()
for i in read_me:
mailist = i.strip()

import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


SENDER = "Sender Name <sender@example.com>"

RECIPIENT = "recipient@example.com"

AWS_REGION = "us-west-2"

SUBJECT = "Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)"

BODY_TEXT = ("Amazon SES Test (Python)\r\n"
             "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the "
             "AWS SDK for Python (Boto)."
            )

BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>
  <p>This email was sent with
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>
      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
            """            
CHARSET = "UTF-8"
# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)
# Try to send the email.
try:
    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing in array like this:

```
Recipients = ['Recipient One <recipient_1@email.com>', 'recipient_2@email.com']
```

or more specifically:

```
 Destination={'ToAddresses': ['recipient_1@email.com', 'recipient_2@email.com']},
```

Comment: Invalid type for parameter Destination.ToAddresses[0], value: ['Recipient One <email1@gmail.com>', 'email2@gmail.com'], type: <type 'list'>, valid types: <type 'basestring'>

Comment: thank you it worked any idea how I can use an email list txt file as a recipient list? something like this maybe mylist = open(list.txt,r)
read_me = mylist.readlines()
for i in read_me:
mailist = i.strip()